# Using AJAX to update information with every click

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, dynamic

Ok I have a table that changes the displayed text once clicked on like the one displayed on http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_database.asp

I'm trying to update it based on each click. 
For example.

```
Page Load > Load news article 1
onClick 1 > Load news article 2
onClick 2 > Load news article 3
```

All I want is for it to change based on each click, to a subsequent value. I have a php mysql database script that will pull the data from the database each time called.

The real question: Should I program the php to return a new table data cell with the new

```
oncLick="showNews($next_number)"
```

or should I leave that up to the AJAX, before it requests the information, just +1 it up.

I'm new to AJAX programming and not that experienced in PHP. I have searched everywhere and apologize if this is a redundant question. Just point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write a php function to support to get the content by id. `showNews(news ID)`. and then pass the newid with the ajax request. no need to change the newsid in the PHP.

Comment: So something like this 
    `str+=1;
     xmlhttp.open("GET","getcustomer.asp?q="+str,true);
     xmlhttp.send();
     }`

Comment: on page load set the str=1; then if you have two separate element to click set the str value respect to the relevant element. or if you are clicking same element just update the str as u did in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing something like this would be simplest:

```
var article = 0;
function showNews(){
   get_article(article);
   // magic
   article+=1;
}
```

To be honest, just pick the way which seems more natural to you. Unless this is only a small part of something huge, it won't matter.

Answer (score 0):

if I understood right, you want to get the next news when clicking on your button...

I suggest you to use jQuery for Ajax request...

It could be like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
     var result = 0;
     $('#myButton').click(function(){
       $.post('phpfunction.php',result,function(r){
             $(document).append(r);
       });
       result ++;
     });
});
</script>
```

And in PHP:

```
<?php
  $result_id = $_POST['result'];
  //SELECT * FROM WHERE id = $result_id;

?>
```

Comment: Please remove the down-vote, I pressed Enter by mistake before finishing my answer...